# React JS Form Validation Before Fetching an API and Redirecting Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a unique React Js form I am trying to validate before submission.

The issue is my onClick function is doing two other processes.

I am **fetching** data and redirecting. I am trying to validate the phone before any of the two processes takes action.

The phone/email/name field should not be empty, if empty the fetch or redirect must not take action.

By default, the number starts with +27.

Methods I have tried, **Joi Form**, **React-Form-Hood**, and **statement**

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Page from "react-page-loading";


function Checkout({ cart, setResponse }) {
  const [contactPreference, setContactPreference] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    setSpinner(true);
    const token = "2c506c6b-d880-36bb-bdba-a035d1464b35";
    const data = {
      transactionReference: "string",
      paymentMethod: "CreditCard",
      checkoutOrderUrl: "http://www.test.com/",
      user: {
        name: name,
        msisdn: "+27" + phone,
        email: email,
      },
      payementMethodDetail: {
        RedirectUrl: "http://localhost:3000/",
        PurchaseEventWebhookUrl: "http://www.test.com",
      },

      bundle: cart.map((item) => ({
        ProductCode: `${item.ProductCode}`,
        Amount: item.amount,
        CurrencyCode: item.currencyCode,
        Quantity: item.quantity,
      })),
    };
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
    await fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/checkout/",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setResponse(response);
      })
      .then(() => {
        setSpinner(false);
        navigate("/payment");
      });
  };

  console.log();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        Name: <input onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
        <form className="form-inline">
          <label className="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
            How should we contact you ??
          </label>
          <select
            onChange={(e) => {
              setContactPreference(e.target.value);
            }}
            className="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"
            id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref"
          >
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            <option value="phone">Phone Number</option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
          </select>
          {contactPreference === "phone" ? (
            <input
              placeholder="+27"
              onChange={(event) => setPhone(event.target.value)}
            />
          ) : contactPreference === "email" ? (
            <input
              placeholder="Email"
              onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
            />
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Proceed to Payment
      </button>
      {spinner && <Page loader={"spin"} color={"#b2fa00"} size={4}></Page>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at checking if the fields are empty? I don't see how this is customary or unique either. You have a bunch of fields and you do not have `if (!name || !phone || !email) return;` or similar

Comment: As a side note, you should put `setSpinner(false)` in a `.finally()` before the first `.then()`, so it's called if the request fails, too.

Comment: @DustInCompetent, thank you. I am failing to understand thought. Do you mind updating my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `required` attribute to input and select elements, put a `ref` on the form element, and in your `handleSubmit` function, use

```
const formValid = formRef.current?.reportValidity()
```

to get a boolean result and have the browser display hints on missing fields.

Comment: Thank you. Please could you update my code.

Comment: @ManassehCodes https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-7tb07l?file=/Checkout.js

Comment: Thank you. This has worked. I am now wondering what it I want to use Radio buttons instead of the dropdown option

Comment: @ManassehCodes You'll want to look up how to write "controlled components" in React. Not just for radio buttons, I noticed you weren't setting the inputs' value from state, only listening to changes.